# Vue.js 2 Alternative to use key as JSON.stringify(obj) to rerender child component on change of obj from xhr callback

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to rerender child component when the array passed by prop has any of its element changed from xhr request. The child component is passed an empty array `(allFiles)` at the beginning and inside the child component I used v-for to display a row for each array element. At any time user can add a new element to the array and that shows few information on each row. As soon as the element is added I make an xhr request to get additional information and when the information is returned I show the new information on the rows.

To achieve this on the child component that holds the rows of the array elements I passed `:key="JSON.stringify(allFiles)"`

The element looks like this:

```
<file-edit-list :all-files="allFiles" :key="JSON.stringify(allFiles)"></file-edit-list>
```

This works. However I have put a `console.log(this.allFiles)` at the created hook of the child element. I see a huge amount of rerender happening for the child component. For each line of the following for in loop where I map the response to the old array, I see a rerender.

```
for (const k in response) {
  if (response[k]) {
    this.allFiles[fileIndex][k] = response[k];
  }
}
```

I don't think this is optimal. How can I make the performance better while keep all my functionality working as is.

Comment: from where are you getting `fileIndex`? please provide more code

Comment: I make only one xhr at a time. On the component I have reactive property `currentIndex`.  When I make an xhr I set the `this.currentIndex` to the index of the array element for which I am making the request. After the xhr returns response I increment the index and make another call. The code I have in my application is following. I put fileIndex to simplify as that is irrelevent to this question.

    `for (const k in response) {if (response[k]) {
    this.allFiles[this.currentIndex][k] = response[k];
  }
}`

The thing that this code indicates is `allFiles` is getting modified.

Comment: please provide more code snippet in order to give a big picture

Comment: I updated how the element html tag looks like. The whole component uses multiple reusable component and is over 200 lines of code. My question is not specific to the code I wrote. It is to ask if there is a better way to rerender vue child component without using JSON.stringify.

Comment: thanks for providing more details and what do you mean by *I see a huge amount of rerender happening for the child component*?

Comment: `allFiles` is array of `IUploadFile`(custom interface) before sending the xhr request I only know the file name. After the file is uploaded, server returns other properties for example GenreName, Artist etc. The for loop sets these. And as soon as one is updated, the child component rerender as the `:key` changes. After xhr I update 8 other properties and the whole component rerender 8 times. So if I upload 8 files, there are 65 rerender of the component. Where optimal is 9 render. Initial render and 8 render after each file uploads. I consider this amount as `huge amount of rerender`